# What is a "pending connection" that might be preventing me from deleting a contact and account?

Tags: account, contact, delete, multiple-contacts

As I'm trying to do some cleanup in a customer's org, I face the following problem when deleting an account:

> Your attempt to delete Mr. Robert Jefferson could not be completed because it is associated with the following pending connections.: Robert Jefferson

I don't remember what a "pending connection" is in this situation, but I do have Multiple Contacts enabled in this org, and there's a single contact related to the account. I can't delete the relationship (because it is the single one linking the contact to an account, probably), and when I try to delete the contact or the account, I get this error message (in the UI and on the console).

Comment: Is s2s enabled in ur org? may be that's the issue...

Comment: It doesn't look like it is activated. I can't even find "Salesforce to Salesforce" inside the Setup menu.